# Help with set proof: $A \cap B = A $ if and only if $A \subseteq B $.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> $A \cap B = A $ if and only if $A \subseteq B $

It's been a while since I've done this sort of proof. I can't think of how I would prove this statement. I'm too used to numerical proofs.

What kind of proof would I use and how?

Answer (score 5):

Suppose $A\not\subset B$, then there exists an $a\in A$ such that $a\notin B$. Hence $a\notin A\cap B$. Thus $A\cap B\neq A$.

Conversely, if $A\cap B=A$ then $A\subset A\cap B$, so for each $a\in A$ we have that $a\in A\cap B$, which implies that $a\in B$. Thus $A\subset B$.

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

1. You have to show both ways (as mentioned in [Hawks' comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1760918/177357)).
2. Use proof by contradiction.
3. Consider one statement is true, then take an element from that set and consider that does not belong to the other. Finally, show that it is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

To prove $A\cap B=A \Rightarrow A\subseteq B$ you can use the identity $B=(A\cap B)\cup(B\setminus A)$. If $A\cap B=A$, then $B=A\cup(B\setminus A)$. Hence $A\subseteq B$.

Answer (score 0):

$(\Rightarrow ):$
  $$A= A \cap B\subseteq B$$
$(\Leftarrow ):$
By definition, $A \cap B\subseteq A$. To see converse note that: For all $x\in A$, by assumption $x\in B$. So $x\in A\cap B$

Answer (score -1):

Let $A\cap B=A$ Show that $A\subseteq B$.

Let $A\subseteq B$, show that $A\cap B=A$.

Where is your problem?

Comment: I don't remember how to show that. I could give examples but that wouldn't constitute a proof.